# Buscar datos de un alumno usando un parámetro con JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, servlets

estoy realizando un programa para colocar en practica todo lo que he aprendido en mi curso de Java. Actualmente puedo buscar los datos de un alumno si busco por su id, supuse que en el caso de una búsqueda por dni o correo debería ser similar. Y pues allí es donde tengo el problema, ya que no me realiza la búsqueda, aunque los pasos son los mismos que para buscar el id. A continuación les dejare imágenes de como esta implementado el código señalando el proceso para consultar el dni, "tambien se visualiza el del id que si funciona". Si me pudiesen ayudar u orientar en donde esta el error mucho lo agradecería.

**Clase Alumno "Entidad"**

```
package beans.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "alumnos")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumnos.findAll",query = "Select a from Alumnos a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumnos.findByIdAlumno",query = "select a from Alumnos a where a.id_alumno = :idAlumno"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumnos.findByPrimerNombre",query = "select a from Alumnos a where a.primer_nombre = :primer_nombre"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumnos.findBySegundoNombre",query = "select a from Alumnos a where a.segundo_nombre = :segundo_nombre"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumnos.findByPrimerApellido",query = "select a from Alumnos a where a.primer_apellido = :primer_apellido"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumnos.findBySegundoApellido",query = "select a from Alumnos a where a.segundo_apellido = :segundo_apellido"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumnos.findByDni",query = "select a from Alumnos a where a.dni = :dni"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumnos.findByFechaNacimiento", query = "select a from Alumnos a where a.fecha_nacimiento = :fecha_nacimiento"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumnos.findByEdad", query = "select a from Alumnos a where a.edad = :edad"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumnos.findByCorreo", query = "select a from Alumnos a where a.correo = :correo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumnos.findByTelefono", query = "select a from Alumnos a where a.telefono = :telefono")
})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Alumnos implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_alumno")
    private Integer id_alumno;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1,max = 45)
    @Column(name = "primer_nombre")
    private String primer_nombre;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    private String segundo_nombre;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "primer_apellido")
    private String primer_apellido;

    @Size(min = 1,max = 45)
    @Column(name = "segundo_apellido")
    private String segundo_apellido;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "dni")
    private String dni;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "fecha_nacimiento")
    private String fecha_nacimiento;

    @Column(name = "edad")
    private int edad;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "correo")
    private String correo;

    @Size(min = 1,max = 45)
    private String telefono;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_representante",referencedColumnName = "id_representante")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Representantes representantes;

    public Alumnos() {}

    public Alumnos(Integer id_alumno)
    {
        this.id_alumno = id_alumno;
    }

    public Alumnos(String dni)
    {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public Alumnos(Integer id_alumno, String primer_nombre, String primer_apellido, String dni, String fecha_nacimiento, String correo) {
        this.id_alumno = id_alumno;
        this.primer_nombre = primer_nombre;
        this.primer_apellido = primer_apellido;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.fecha_nacimiento = fecha_nacimiento;
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public Alumnos(Integer id_alumno, String primer_nombre, String primer_apellido, String dni, String fecha_nacimiento, int edad, String correo) {
        this.id_alumno = id_alumno;
        this.primer_nombre = primer_nombre;
        this.primer_apellido = primer_apellido;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.fecha_nacimiento = fecha_nacimiento;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public Alumnos(String primer_nombre, String primer_apellido, String dni, String fecha_nacimiento, String correo) {
        this.primer_nombre = primer_nombre;
        this.primer_apellido = primer_apellido;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.fecha_nacimiento = fecha_nacimiento;
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public Alumnos(String primer_nombre, String primer_apellido, String dni, String fecha_nacimiento, int edad, String correo) {
        this.primer_nombre = primer_nombre;
        this.primer_apellido = primer_apellido;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.fecha_nacimiento = fecha_nacimiento;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public Alumnos(String primer_nombre, String segundo_nombre, String primer_apellido, String segundo_apellido, String dni, String fecha_nacimiento, int edad, String correo, String telefono) {
        this.primer_nombre = primer_nombre;
        this.segundo_nombre = segundo_nombre;
        this.primer_apellido = primer_apellido;
        this.segundo_apellido = segundo_apellido;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.fecha_nacimiento = fecha_nacimiento;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.correo = correo;
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public Alumnos(Integer id_alumno, String primer_nombre, String segundo_nombre, String primer_apellido, String segundo_apellido, String dni, String fecha_nacimiento, int edad, String correo, String telefono) {
        this.id_alumno = id_alumno;
        this.primer_nombre = primer_nombre;
        this.segundo_nombre = segundo_nombre;
        this.primer_apellido = primer_apellido;
        this.segundo_apellido = segundo_apellido;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.fecha_nacimiento = fecha_nacimiento;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.correo = correo;
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public Integer getId_alumno() {
        return id_alumno;
    }

    public void setId_alumno(Integer id_alumno) {
        this.id_alumno = id_alumno;
    }

    public String getPrimer_nombre() {
        return primer_nombre;
    }

    public void setPrimer_nombre(String primer_nombre) {
        this.primer_nombre = primer_nombre;
    }

    public String getSegundo_nombre() {
        return segundo_nombre;
    }

    public void setSegundo_nombre(String segundo_nombre) {
        this.segundo_nombre = segundo_nombre;
    }

    public String getPrimer_apellido() {
        return primer_apellido;
    }

    public void setPrimer_apellido(String primer_apellido) {
        this.primer_apellido = primer_apellido;
    }

    public String getSegundo_apellido() {
        return segundo_apellido;
    }

    public void setSegundo_apellido(String segundo_apellido) {
        this.segundo_apellido = segundo_apellido;
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public String getFecha_nacimiento() {
        return fecha_nacimiento;
    }

    public void setFecha_nacimiento(String fecha_nacimiento) {
        this.fecha_nacimiento = fecha_nacimiento;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getCorreo() {
        return correo;
    }

    public void setCorreo(String correo) {
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public Representantes getRepresentantes()
    {
        return representantes;
    }

    public void setRepresentantes(Representantes representantes)
    {
        this.representantes = representantes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Alumnos [idAlumno: "+id_alumno+", Primer Nombre: "+primer_nombre+" Segundo Nomobre: "+segundo_nombre+", Primer Apellido: "+primer_apellido+", Segundo Apellido: "+segundo_apellido+", DNI: "+dni+", Fecha de Nacimiento: "+fecha_nacimiento+", Edad: "+edad+", Correo: "+correo+", Telefono: "+telefono+"]";
    }
}
```

**Interfaz JPA**

```
package beans.eis;

import beans.domain.Alumnos;
import java.util.List;

public interface AlumnosDao
{
    public List<Alumnos> findAllAlumnos();

    public Alumnos findAlumnosById(Alumnos alumnos);

    public Alumnos findAlumnosByDni(Alumnos alumnos);

    public Alumnos findAlumnosByCorreo(Alumnos alumnos);

    public void insertAlumnos(Alumnos alumnos);

    public void updateAlumnos(Alumnos alumnos);

    public void deleteAlumnos(Alumnos alumnos);
}
```

**Implementación Interfaz JPA**

```
package beans.eis;

import beans.domain.Alumnos;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class AlumnosDaoImpl implements AlumnosDao
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Sistema_Escolar")
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Alumnos> findAllAlumnos()
    {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Alumnos.findAll").getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public Alumnos findAlumnosById(Alumnos alumnos)
    {
        return em.find(Alumnos.class, alumnos.getId_alumno());
    }

    @Override
    public Alumnos findAlumnosByDni(Alumnos alumnos)
    {
        return em.find(Alumnos.class, alumnos.getDni());
    }

    @Override
    public Alumnos findAlumnosByCorreo(Alumnos alumnos)
    {
        return em.find(Alumnos.class, alumnos.getCorreo());
    }

    @Override
    public void insertAlumnos(Alumnos alumnos)
    {
        em.persist(alumnos);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateAlumnos(Alumnos alumnos)
    {
        em.merge(alumnos);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAlumnos(Alumnos alumnos)
    {
        em.remove(em.merge(alumnos));
    }
}
```

**Interfaz del Servicio**

```
package beans.service;

import beans.domain.Alumnos;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface AlumnoServiceLocal
{
    public List<Alumnos> listarAlumnos();

    public Alumnos encontrarAlumnosPorId(Alumnos alumnos);

    public Alumnos encontrarAlumnosPorDni(Alumnos alumnos);

    public Alumnos encontrarAlumnosPorCorreo(Alumnos alumnos);

    public void registrarAlumno(Alumnos alumnos);

    public void modificarAlumno(Alumnos alumnos);

    public void eliminarAlumno(Alumnos alumnos);
}
```

**Implementación de la interfaz de servicio**

```
package beans.service;

import beans.domain.Alumnos;
import beans.eis.AlumnosDao;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Stateless
public class AlumnosServiceImpl implements AlumnoServiceLocal, AlumnosServiceRemote
{
    @Inject
    private AlumnosDao alumnoDao;

    @Override
    public List<Alumnos> listarAlumnos()
    {
        return alumnoDao.findAllAlumnos();
    }

    @Override
    public Alumnos encontrarAlumnosPorId(Alumnos alumnos)
    {
        return alumnoDao.findAlumnosById(alumnos);
    }

    @Override
    public Alumnos encontrarAlumnosPorDni(Alumnos alumnos)
    {
        return alumnoDao.findAlumnosByDni(alumnos);
    }

    @Override
    public Alumnos encontrarAlumnosPorCorreo(Alumnos alumnos)
    {
        return alumnoDao.findAlumnosByCorreo(alumnos);
    }

    @Override
    public void registrarAlumno(Alumnos alumnos)
    {
        alumnoDao.insertAlumnos(alumnos);
    }

    @Override
    public void modificarAlumno(Alumnos alumnos)
    {
        alumnoDao.updateAlumnos(alumnos);
    }

    @Override
    public void eliminarAlumno(Alumnos alumnos)
    {
        alumnoDao.deleteAlumnos(alumnos);
    }
}
```

**Parte del servlet**

```
private void buscarFichaAlumno(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String dni = request.getParameter("dni");
        System.out.println(dni);
        Alumnos alumno = new Alumnos(dni);
        alumno = this.alumnosServiceLocal.encontrarAlumnosPorDni(alumno);
        System.out.println(alumno);
    }
```

**Error que arroja la consola**

[image: Error en consola, observar que trae los datos de todos los alumnos en un listado, pero cuando se trata de obtener solo por el dni no los muestra]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que dices,

> en el caso de una búsqueda por dni o correo debería ser similar

, no es del todo correcto. `EntityManager.find` busca solo por id - https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html. A partir de aquí tu razonamiento se va un poco al carajo.

Para buscar por dni debes implementar tu propia sentencia, algo así:

```
public List<Alumnos> findAlumnosByDni(Alumnos alumnos) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("select a from Alumnos a where a.dni = " + alumnos.getDni());
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

O si prefieres `q.getSingleResult()` pero esto es peligroso si la sentencia devuelve mas de un resultado (se supone que por dni no puede ser pero por algún otro criterio...). Tambien puedes pasar directamente el string dni al método y no todo el bean. Cuestión de gustos.

Pues es, a ver si te sirve.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, desconocía que el EntityManager solo funcionaba con el id y en el curso que estoy viendo no mencionan nada de eso. Por eso supuse que aplicaría igual al correo o el dni, lo voy a aplicar en este momento, muchísimas gracias y que tenga buen día.

Comment: Disculpa probando lo que me dijiste en efecto me puedo traer el numero de dni siempre y cuando no posea números y para el correo no me funciona tampoco, por que sucede esto?

Comment: Siento responder tan tarde. Si no te funciona para el correo te debe lanzar algún error, a ver si nos da alguna pista. No entiendo qué quieres decir _"... me puedo traer el numero de dni siempre y cuando no posea números..."_

Comment: Con los números me funciona, pero si aplico al correo me daba error, lo que hice fue aplicar un setParameter y si me permitió agregar datos alfanuméricos. Muchas gracias por ayudarme.